# Counting total per day with my result in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 50 rows/entrys in my table Orders. I have a column, that holds when the order is claimed at, named `claimed_at`.

The date in this field are in this format: 2011-10-03 07:07:33

This is in the format (yy/mm/dd time).

I also have a column called `price`, this `price` is how much they paid.

I would like to display totals per day.

So for 6 orders from the date 2011-10-03, it should take the 6 order's `price` value, and plus them together.

So I can display:

```
2011-10-03  -- Total: 29292 Euros
2011-10-02  -- Total: 222 Euros
2011-09-28  -- Total: 4437 Euros
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want help with the php or the sql? What type of database are you using?

Comment: what is the data type of the column claimed_at?

Comment: datetime is the column claimed_at

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) functionality of MySQL in conjuction with some [DATE conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
SELECT DATE(claimed_at) AS day
    , SUM(price) AS total
FROM Orders
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field say day with DATE_FORMAT(claimed_at,'%Y-%m-%d') AS day , sum the price and group by day so you will get the result you want.

Something like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(claimed_at,'%Y-%m-%d') AS day,SUM(price) as total FROM orders GROUP BY day ORDER BY day DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping like this :

```
SELECT claimed_at, SUM(price) AS total 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY claimed_at
```

You need to use function to get only date part(not time) in grouping. I dont know which function is used in mysql, in MSSQL it's CONVERT() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRUNC(claimed_at), SUM(PRICE) 
FROM my_orders_table 
GROUP BY TRUNC(claimed_at)
```